# piping a tone generator to aplay()

Tags: audio, pipe

I thought it would be a simple task ...
- platform: linux on laptop
- language: python
- object: generate tone to be heard on speaker or headphones. Tone will be modified in real-time, many times per second (think about a metal-finder)

Initial design was to generate a tone in python and pipe it to aplay().
Since *aplay* consume data at a known rate (the sampling rate), I thought my tone generator would not have to care about timing if silences (between tones) where generated at normal sampling rate (null amplitude).

First result show an important time lag (many seconds). I found that the pipe is fairly long by default (64KB). That's 8 seconds of samples (at 8Khz).
I found a way to reduce the pipe size at 4KB but it is still too long (0.5s lag).

Sampling at a very high frequency would reduce the lag but I don't like that solution.

Second approach was to generate a real silence (no sample) during a silence and the generator would sleep() during the silence.
Result is that *aplay* complains about *underrunning* and, for some reason, the tones were truncated and mishandled (bad rendering).

So, my question is:
What are the best ways to send a tone to the audio stack without piping?

Comment: I wrote an audio server which receives a stream then sits there feeding it into an OpenAL event loop to render the audio ... works fine yet not trivial ... part of project where I replaced Apple's firmware which lives underneath all the apps to play streaming audio from arbitrary HLS sources ... not for the faint of heart ... the portion you need is less than two pages of OpenAL code to act as the server

Comment: I found sndObj for Python and it seems it will do the job . But it does not exist for Python3. It's a shame that Python3 do not have a decent audio library.

Comment: if you post your sndObj solution as an answer to this question maybe someone will give it a python3 working alternative